# Why cant I use a variable for pipeline in a $lookup in an aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So I'm using multiple pipelines, to return different item feeds but in order to do so I to storing the pipeline definition in data and then use that as the variable for the pipeline on the $lookup but when I use the below it works when the aggregation is pasted into the $lookup.pipeline but not when referenced with a variable in data like in the below.

```
[{
 $match: {
  $expr: {
   $in: [
    '$customerNo',
    [
     'C10909'
    ]
   ]
  },
  active: true,
  'types.type': 'item',
  'types.active': true
 }
}, {
 $unwind: {
  path: '$types'
 }
}, {
 $lookup: {
  from: 'itemPipelines',
  localField: 'types.pipeline',
  foreignField: '_id',
  as: 'pipeline'
 }
}, {
 $unwind: {
  path: '$pipeline'
 }
}, {
 $lookup: {
  from: 'customer',
  localField: 'customerNo',
  foreignField: '_id',
  as: 'customer'
 }
}, {
 $unwind: {
  path: '$customer'
 }
}, {
 $lookup: {
  from: 'items',
  'let': {
   customer: '$customer',
   stockBuffer: 10
  },
  pipeline: '$pipeline.pipline',
  as: 'items'
 }
}]
```

I get the error 'pipeline' option must be specified as an array

Has anyone ever tried this or have done similar?

Comment: This is a damn interesting question. I assume that mongodb does not yet support this kind of behavior, as in their documentation (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/data-federation/supported-unsupported/pipeline/lookup-stage/) no `<expression>` data type (only array) is mentioned.

Comment: I doubt it's supported and I doubt it will be. Mixing business data and applied query in the same document looks weird to me

Comment: I think there is a use case especially when e.g. trying to define KPIs (or other metrics) dynamically. There are other SQL based applications where you can write SQL statements to define these kinds of metrics and store their definition. I can imagine defining such a system for document based databases is not easy without this functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, The pipeline does not support expression input from internal document's properties, It requires an empty array (`[]`) or array of objects with specified stages,

See a similar requirement as yours, [Allow from field of $lookup and $graphLookup to be an expression](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22497)
, but still in the backlog,

You can submit a future request or just vote and comment on your requirement in the above backlog.

For now, you can divide that one query into multiple queries and use that dynamic stages.